# JUNIT : Get the input file from the file path in config folder

Tags: java, junit

```
@Test
public void testProviderDetails_ValidFile()        
{

       ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

        // Throws null pointer exception here
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("services/src/text/resources/config/test.txt").getFile());

        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

}
```

> I want to get the file path which is placed in the
>   **src/test/resources/config** folder.

But i am getting null pointer exception as i mentioned above.Can any help me regarding this ??

Is anything i have missed in the above code ?

*I have also tried the below codes :*

```
   File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("c:/dev/Provider_Services/services/src/text/resources/config/test.txt").getFile()); and

    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("test.txt").getFile());

   File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("config/test.txt").getFile());
```

**Got the same error !!**

Comment: Try omitting "services/src/text/resources", since the contents should have been copied to the root of the jar

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Maven and its default settings.. so,src/test/resources is already in the classpath. So, just give config/test.txt as the parameter in the getresource method. It will work.

Comment: yes prasad, i am using maven i will your sugesstion

Comment: i got the same error , when the path is config/text.txt . Couldn't able to find what i have missed here

Comment: hmm... is it src/text or src/test? Also, is src/test/resources mentioned as source folder in the java build path?